# Strange execution times in t-sql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have two stored procedures, the first one calls the second ..
If I execute the second one alone it takes over 5 minutes to complete..
But when executed within the first one it takes little over 1 minute..
What is the reason !

Here is the first one

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[schRefreshPriceListItemGroups] as

begin tran
delete from PriceListItemGroups
if @@error !=0 goto rolback
Insert PriceListItemGroups(comno,t$cuno,t$cpls,t$cpgs,t$dsca,t$cpru)
SELECT distinct c.comno,c.t$cuno, c.t$cpls,I.t$cpgs,g.t$dsca,g.t$cpru
    FROM    TTCCOM010nnn    C
    JOIN    TTDSLS032nnn    PL  ON  PL.comno    =   c.Comno     and PL.t$cpls   =   c.t$cpls
    JOIN    TTIITM001nnn    I   ON  I.t$item    =   pl.t$item   AND I.comno     =   pl.comNo
    JOIN    TTCMCS024nnn    G   ON  g.T$cprg    =   I.t$cpgs    AND g.comno     =   I.Comno
 WHERE  c.t$cpls !='' 
order by comno desc, t$cuno, t$cpgs
if @@error !=0 goto rolback
-----------------------------------------------------
Exec scrRefreshCustomersCatalogs
-----------------------------------------------------
commit tran


return
rolback:
Rollback tran
```

---

And  the second one

```
Alter proc scrRefreshCustomersCatalogs as
declare @baanIds table(id int identity(1,1),baanId varchar(12))
declare @baanId varchar(12),@i int, @n int
Insert @baanIds(BaanId)
select baanId from ftElBaanIds()
SELECT @I=1,@n=max(id) from @baanIds
select @i,@n
Begin tran
if @@error !=0 goto xRollBack
WHILE @I <=@n
    Begin
        select @baanId=baanId from @baanIds where id=@i
        if @@error !=0 goto xRollBack
        Delete from customersCatalogs where comno+'-'+t$cuno=@baanId
        print Convert(varchar,@i)+' baanId='+@baanId
        Insert customersCatalogs exec customersCatalog @baanId
        if @@error !=0 goto xRollBack

        set @i=@i+1;
    end

Commit Tran
Update statistics customersCatalogs with fullscan

Return
xRollBack:
Print '*****Rolling back*************'
Rollback tran
```

Comment: What I'm more worried about is your table and field naming o_Ô TTCCOM010nnn TTIITM001nnn TTCMCS024nnn what?

Comment: Well, these are set of tables cached from BaaN ERP.. and we have a web application that hosts somewhat BaaN functionality over teh web. So to be consistent with BaaN and Web application, we are using the same naming conventions.. But the schema is 100% compliant with native sql (sql 2005).

Comment: @Matti Virkkunen 
I c. It looks coming from neanderthal..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to say.  When run within the first SP, you will be inside two transactions.

I assume the second SP does something indirectly with the data insert in the first SP (PriceListItemGroups), so when you are running the second SP by itself, is the same data also insert into that table?

In the first SP, it also seems odd that you are inserting with an ORDER BY.  While I know that's technically allowed, in almost every case, it's unnecessary.